# Is there an overhead view?

Tags: planet-coaster

I'm trying to get a handle on my park and what it looks like. and ideally I'd like a bird's eye overhead sort of view where I can look down on things, instead of the default which is kinda looking at them from the side. I see I can tilt the camera with some combination of the scroll wheel and the arrow keys, but I can't seem to get that working with my mouse.

Is this possible in the options somewhere? I didn't immediately see anything when I looked. (Or if there is another way for me to tilt the camera, maybe then I could do it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a bird's eye view of your park by zooming out and holding down and dragging the middle click button. Below is an example of what that looks like. (Excuse the negative funds) [image: Overhead view of park.]

EDIT: I do not believe there is a command to toggle to an overhead view. The available camera controls are:

```
Pan Camera Forward:     W
Pan Camera Backward:    S
Pan Camera Left:        A
Pan Camera Right:       D
Rotate Camera Left:     Q
Rotate Camera Right:    E
Zoom Camera In:         Page Up
Zoom Camera Out:        Page Down

Toggle Freelook Mode:   T
Pan Camera Up:          E
Pan Camera Down:        Q
```

As an alternative to the mouse middle click issue, you should have the same functionality by pressing both left and right click down and dragging your mouse.

Comment: Is there any other way? I can't get my middle click button to work to accomplish this, which might be an issue with my mouse.

Comment: @Ash how can you be a high rep user and a mod in this place and have issues with your middle mouse button? :D

Comment: @simbaque because that has nothing to do with how well or not my mouse actually works?

Comment: @Ash You must have missed the new logitech G5000 that has repairs based solely on rep.

Comment: @Ash I found an alternative to the middle click issue and updated my answer.